# Informal language: “you guy’s” vs. “your guy’s”

Tags: possessives, formality, saxon-genitive

*You guys* and *Your guys* are somewhat informal in English language.

Typical example usages:

> Do you guys want to come around to watch movies tomorrow night?

Is addressing a party of more than one, extending an invitation the them.

Similarly:

> Do you guys sell pencils?

Said to a shop assistant, is asking whether the collection of people (the store), sell pencils.

In both of these examples, *you guys* refers to a collective entity.

'Your guys' might refer to the ownership of 'guys' by a single person.

eg.

> Can you send your guys around to my house to clean my windows?

In this example, the guys belong to, in the sense of 'are employed by', the person being asked.

And similarly:

> Can you drop your guys' tools around at mine to be cleaned?

Here, the guys belong to the employer, and the tools belong to each of the guys.

*The question is*, what about when I'm referring to ownership by a collective entity?

Eg:

> I love your guy's beer.

Is this correct?

Or should it be:

> I love you guy's beer.

Comment: This is a great place to use "all y'all's."

Comment: In practice I suspect you either drop the redundant "guys" at that point, and say _I love your beer_ or rephrase to avoid the issue _I love the beer you guys make_ rather than go with the awkward _you guys' beer_

Answer (score 1):

> I love your guy's beer

Would mean, that I love the beer that your guy is having. For example, if I said to Bob's wife, "I love your guy's beer", it would meen I love Bob's beer.

> I love you guy's beer

Would mean, that I am telling the beer that I love you, which doesn't make much sense I guess.

I think what you would mean is "I love your guys' beer", meaning that I love the beer of the guy's workers/friends.

If you want to include the guy, I think you'd have to rephrase it, for example "I love the beer you guys make".